# передается ненужное значение переменной

Tags: c, list

Добавляю переменные с следующей последовательности:

```
void addCar() {
    int i;
    //declare local variables for a car
    char aRegistration[10];
    char aModel[30];
    char aColour[30];
    int aNum;
    bool aReserved;
    long anAmount;
    int  valid_input = 0;    /* when 1, data is valid and loop is exited */

    struct LinearNode *aNode;
    struct car *aCar;
    struct LinearNode *current, *previous, *last;

    // add SIZE nodes to the list

    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

        printf("**************Car %d:**************\n", i + 1);


            while (valid_input == 0) {
                printf("Enter registration number (format: yyDnnnn): \n");
                scanf("%s", aRegistration);
                int len = strlen(aRegistration);
                if (len == 7) {
                    if (((aRegistration[0] == '0' && aRegistration[1] >= '1' && aRegistration[1] <= '9') ||
                        (aRegistration[0] == '1' && aRegistration[1] >= '0' && aRegistration[1] <= '4')) && (aRegistration[2] == 'D')
                        && ((isdigit(aRegistration[3]) >0) && (isdigit(aRegistration[4]) > 0) && (isdigit(aRegistration[5]) > 0) &&
                            (isdigit(aRegistration[6]) > 0)))
                        valid_input = 1;
                    else  printf("\007Error: Do not match the format!\n");
                }
            }


        printf("Enter model: \n");
        scanf("%s", aModel);

        printf("Enter colour:\n");
        scanf("%s", aColour);


        do {
            printf("Enter number: \n");
            scanf("%d", &aNum);
        } while (aNum > 3);


        //getchar();
        //fgets(aModel, sizeof(aModel), stdin);
        printf("Car is not reserved at this momemnt\n");
        aReserved = false;
        printf("Amount is 0, because car is unreserved.\n");
        anAmount = 0;
    }

    // create space for new node and new data element
    aCar = (struct car *)malloc(sizeof(struct car));
    aNode = (struct LinearNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct LinearNode));


    if (aNode == NULL)
        printf("Error - no space for the new node\n");
    else { // add data part to the node

        strcpy(aCar->registration, aRegistration);
        strcpy(aCar->model, aModel);
        strcpy(aCar->colour, aColour);

        aCar->num = aNum;
        aCar->reserved = aReserved;
        aCar->amount = anAmount;
        aNode->element = aCar; //assign address of element to list
        aNode->next = NULL;

        //add node to front of the list
        if (isEmpty())
            front = aNode;
        else {
            current = previous = front;
            if (previous == current)
            {
                aNode->next = front;
                front = aNode;
            }
            else
                if (current == NULL)
                {
                    last = aNode;
                    previous->next = last;
                }

                else

                {
                    previous->next = aNode;
                    aNode->next = current;
                }
            //end else
        }//end else
    }//end for
}//end addNodes
```

Когда отображаю результат, регистрационный номер отображается следующим образом:

```
Registration Number: `04D1234Ford`.
```

`Ford` берется из далеестоящей переменной и сам добавляется к регистрационному номеру.
В чем мой недочет, никак не могу найти.

Comment: По приведенному вами кусочку не понятно, что вы делали с переменными в промежутке и как выводили регистрационный номер. Обычно такие ошибки совершаются очень далеко от места обнаружения. Вы же потом используете `aRegistration` и записываете его в `aCar->registration` - сколько места вы выделяете этому полю?

Comment: Извините за столько поздний ответ. Вывожу я данные как обычно: `printf("Registration: %s\n", current->element->registration);`

Comment: Короче говоря, очень похоже, что у вас нет нулевого завершающего символа, и выводится `Ford` из следующего поля.

Comment: а где этот символ должен присутствовать и как он обозначается?

Comment: Просто нулевой байт. Строки в стиле C - это массив символов, в котором последовательно идут буквы строки, а потом - нулевой байт (не символ '0', а именно 0). Т.е. "Hello" - это реально 6 байт - 'H','e','l','l','o' и нулик.